# Issue with 'canvas' Package Installation on Windows Node.js Environment

Tags: node.js, windows, canvas

Hi StackOverflow Community; i'm having difficulty trying to install the `canvas` package in my Node.js project in a Windows environment. The error messages suggest issues with missing dependencies and the build process not finding certain header files and GTK-related libraries.

Complete error: [Click here](https://pastebin.com/iiz6rDa1)

I have taken the following steps to resolve the issue:

- Installed Visual Studio Build Tools.
- Downloaded and added the GTK binaries to my system's PATH.
- Cleared Yarn's cache using `yarn cache clean`.
- Retried the installation with `yarn add canvas`.
- Updated Node.js to the latest LTS version.
- Removed `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`, then
  reinstalled dependencies with `yarn install`.
- Tried with `npm install canvas`.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. The error messages specifically mention missing GTK-related files. I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly install the `canvas` package on a Windows machine.